Masking IP addresses, names, and emails in Grafana before downloading logs
I am fetching multiple logs from Loki in Grafana, and I want to mask sensitive data (like IP addresses, email addresses, and names) before downloading the logs using the Grafana UI.
The requirement is as follows:
Logs should remain in their original form when viewed in Grafana.
When downloaded, the logs must have sensitive data (e.g., IPs, emails, names) masked.
What I’ve tried:
I attempted to use the following LogQL query with a replace function to mask IP addresses:
{filename="PATH"}
| regexp "(?P<ip>[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3})"
| line_format "{{ replace .line .ip \"***\" }}" 

However, this approach does not work. I’m unsure if it’s an issue with how replace is used in the query or if there’s another solution I should try.
Is there a way to achieve this masking behavior in Grafana/Loki while still maintaining the original logs for display? Any ideas or alternative approaches are welcome.


Nothing in your query indicates presence of line label. If you want to use pseudo-label containing full line - it's __line__. 2. [replace] has a different signature. Use replace .ip "***" __line__ or __line__ | replace .ip "***". 3. You can use ` to avoid escaping quotes: line_format`{{__line__ | replace .ip "***"}}` 


Feel free to make this into answer, if you feel there is something worth keeping for posterity.

Thank you for your response. The issue with the current query is that the replace function within line_format is applied to the entire line, not just the IP address field. This causes unintended replacements throughout the log lines, where every matching character of the IP address (0-9 and .) is replaced, resulting in distorted output.
The line are looking like this now: Dec 17*** 10***:25***:50***

I don't get how you ended up with this (neither what is exactly your current message - use backticks to show unformatted message in comments). But when I run query like yours, but with corrected replace - only IP is replaced.

But more generally, your approach is limited to a single IP. Consider using regexReplaceAll like | line_format `{{regexReplaceAll "<your regex here>" __line__ "***"}}` 

Thank you for the solution! I am now using regexReplaceAll like this:
| line_format {{regexReplaceAll "" line "***"}}
and it’s working perfectly, just as I am expecting.
